# Conditional Attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, conditional-statements, conditional-compilation

A quick C# question, I would like to know that in my project > Properties > Build, there is a check **"Define DEBUG constant"**, so if I check that and then do this,

```
[Conditional(DEBUG)]
public static void Foo() {
      Console.WriteLine("Executed Foo");
}
```

See it's not **"DEBUG"** its the **DEBUG** constant. So will this be okay? Or do I have to add the **"DEBUG"** in the Conditional Compilation Symbols in the Project settings? Or **#define** it?

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what happened?

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure you need to do:

```
[Conditional("Debug")] or [Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

Or you could define your own constant such as:

```
const string DEBUG = "DEBUG";
```

Then use that

```
[Conditional(DEBUG)]
```

This will have to be accompanied by the `#define DEBUG` declaration. See [Conditional C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add double quotes for this to work:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")] // <- Works the DEBUG define
public static void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("Executed Foo");
}
```